# How to delete Fetch Index Element in Xcode

Tags: core-data, xcode9.2

In Xcode 9.2 in core data model (under .xcdatamodeld file) a Fetch Index Element can be added under an entity. **But how can it be deleted?**
I created one by mistake and can't delete. That is why Xcode gives me a warning: "*A fetch index should have one or more elements*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the fetch index in the model editor.

[image]

Press the "delete" key on your keyboard.

[image]

The fetch index is now gone.

Comment: I was trying to delete from menu. Couldn't guess it would be so easy. Thanks a lot.